# Why is the button on my site not working?

Tags: web, checkbox, input, menu, label

If you look here... http://matiny.tk/Mixed%20Swim/Mixed.html
This is a simple site I'm making. It uses Bootstrap to switch the menu when the screen shrinks. Nicely enough, the Menu label/checkbox combo is not working, though it has worked on another site of mine. This is the relevant code...

```
<label for="menulogo" id="menulabel" class="visible-sm visible-xs"><img src="Menu.png"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="menulogo">
</nav>

<nav id="menu">
    <a href="" id="one" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">SHOP</a>
    <a href="" id="two" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="" id="three" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">BLOG</a>
    <a href="" id="four" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">GALLERY</a>
    <a href="" id="five" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">CONTACT</a>
</nav>

label {
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

#menulogo {
    opacity: 0;

}


#menu a {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    height: 75px;

}

#menu {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;

}

#menulogo:checked + #menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You are closing the nav tag with </nav> on the 3rd line. But you are never opening it. Could you provide us with a complete example on this site: http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Matiny/k6jfT/

Comment: Ah, nevermind. It was a problem with the selector... #menulogo:checked + #menu Only works with a certain arrangement of elements.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my order of elements was incorrect. If one is going to use something like... #menulogo:checked + #menu, then the + or ~ selector means that the nav with #menu has to go right after the checkbox input, like so...

```
  <label for="menulogo" id="menulabel" class="visible-sm visible-xs"><img src="Menu.png">   MENU</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="menulogo">
<!--These must be in sequence-->
  <nav id="menu">
    <a href="" id="one" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">SHOP</a>
    <a href="" id="two" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="" id="three" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">BLOG</a>
    <a href="" id="four" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">GALLERY</a>
    <a href="" id="five" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
```